# How to stock NSString in Core Data?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data

I have a model that follows this:

[image: Model]

Then I want to stock a city from a `UITableView`. The problem is, that I want to hold them in the iPhone (Database) until it reach 10, after that it erases the first and adds the last. I have the idea, but I can't just reach to add anything and i'm confused.

[image]

When I click a city, it pushes to the next view sending from a response JSON the id and the name of the city.. Thats ok. But I want to store those in order to make the same call but from another `UITableView` (under it) So it's like the "Last cities searched" something lik that.

I want to save the id,name and after that load it in the other tableView showing only the name. With that i'm Ok, but I can't reach to make the stock happend.

Code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

DetailTaxi *detailView = [[DetailTaxi alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];


NSString *nomville = [[_jsonDict objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"label"];
NSString *idVille = [[_jsonDict objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"];

detailView.title = nomville;
detailView.idVille = idVille;

NSLog(@"Valor: %@", nomville);
NSLog(@"Valor: %@", idVille);


AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSString *insert = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@,%@",idVille,nomville];
NSManagedObject *newVille;


NSArray *insertVilles = [insert componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

for(NSString *insert in insertVilles) {
    newVille = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Ville" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [newVille setValue:[insertVilles objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"id"];
    [newVille setValue:[insertVilles objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"nom"];
}


[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new attribute of type NSDate which you set to the current date upon creating a new entry. Once you retrieve the cities again, use a sort descriptor to sort the cities by the time they were saved and use a fetch limit.

If deleting the previous cities is necessary, the date attribute will prove useful as well.

Comment: What error are you getting? When is the error happening? Are you actually saving the context after you create the object?